# Non form related HTML in form tag #accessibility

Tags: html, accessibility

I recently turned a design in to HTML and CSS to be implemented by our back-end developers. For a search result page I used two `form` tags. One for the search bar and one for the sidebar with filters.

The back-end devs requested if I could just wrap everything in one `form` tag instead.

Due to the layout and not yet available CSS subgrid the only way to get both parts in one form wrapper is to wrap the entire content (the search results) in a `form` tag.

Something about this doesn't feel right even though I can't seem to find anything online other than that it's allowed to have regular HTML-tags in a `form` element.

My solution would be to turn both the `form` tags into `fieldsets` with each a `legend` to indicate what part of the form it is.

Would this be okay accessibility wise? VoiceOver doesn't seem to care about what's inside the form tag. All form fields are listed separately in the Form Controls menu.
[image: Visualization of the HTML]

Comment: [The `form` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#form) might be interesting, too in your case. You can assign form elements to a form without wrapping them inside the form element.

Comment: I thought `form { display: contents }` might help applying your layout while wrapping only part of it inside a form but apparently it removes the form from the accessibility tree, though, which is no good.

Comment: The layout suggests that checking filters will immediately submit the form, is that right?

Comment: @Andy That is indeed correct, checking filters will instantly submit the form and refresh the page. This is a MVP, we will eventually turn this in to Angular.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you’re suggesting a good solution and it shouldn’t pose any issues to assistive technology, if you’re respecting some points:

- The form should use `role="search"` or have an accessible name
- The form elements must stay at the beginning of that landmark
- Each field needs a label, in the wireframe the text input doesn’t have one
- Also each group of checkboxes needs a fieldset, since otherwise the headlines (type, category) will not be announced
- You find a solution for the immediate submission of the form when changing a value (if applicable)
- Any form elements inside the form will be submitted as well, so beware of their names to not overwrite form data (*numbers per page*)

### Functions of the form tag

[The `form` role is a *landmark* role](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#form), meaning it’s purpose for accessibility is to provide an anchor to jump to the form via shortcuts or from an index of forms.

What’s included in the form also determines which values will be submitted to the server, if that’s not done via JavaScript. And last but not least, it determines what elements trigger *implicit submission*, f.e. when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or the Return key on a touch keyboard while inside a text input.

I do not believe assistive technology does anything other than use the landmark role.

In your case, you should use the `search` role instead, since it is a search form. If you don’t, you need to provide a name for the form via `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby`.

Since the **form elements are at the beginning of the `search`** or `form` landmark, it should be fine. The end of a landmark is not announced.

```html
<form role="search">
  <input type="search" aria-label="Search for">
  <button>Search</button>

  <fieldset aria-label="Filters">
    <fieldset>Type</fieldset>
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Type filter 1</label>
```

### Changes of context on input

The wireframe suggests that changing the value of a checkbox’ or the select, the form is submitted automatically.

If this is so, you also need to mind that for users of assistive technology, this *change of context* can be disorienting and unexpected.

[Understanding Success Criterion 3.2.2: On Input](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/on-input.html) explains that you can work around this by indicating that the form will update immediately, or by using an additional button.

See also [Does faceted search fail accessibility?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/118488/does-faceted-search-fail-accessibility)

Comment: Thanks for the extremely detailed answer Andy. The fields do have hidden labels, that's taken care of. As well as the role="search". I see that my designed mockup isn't exactly right, each set of filters has its own fieldset. I will update the image for future visitors. Thanks for pointing me to the change of context, that's something I will look into.